# Maximum Number of Elements’ Orders Necessary to Determine Isomorphism Class of Abelian Group Order 16

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $|G|=16$ and $G$ be Abelian. Using the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, I want to calculate the maximum number of elements necessary to find the orders of so that I am able to determine its isomorphism class.

I also solved the same question for Abelian groups of order $9$ and $18$. I am just having difficulty with doing a similar procedure with order $16$.

I was able to determine each of the orders of the elements in each isomorphism class, but I don’t know how to go about using this information in the same manner as I did when I solved the problem for orders $9$ and $18$. For anyone who wants to try the problem, the orders are:

$\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ has $8$ order $16$, $4$ order $8$, $2$ order $4$, and $1$ order $2$.
$\mathbb{Z}_8 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ has $0$ order $16$, $8$ order $8$, $4$ order $4$, and $3$ order $2$.
$\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ has $0$ order $16$, $0$ order $8$, $8$ order $4$, and $7$ order $2$.
$\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{
Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ has $15$ order $2$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: My issue is that I know I need to know every element’s order in each of the classes. I just don’t know where to go from there. I provided the orders of the elements for anyone who wants to try the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is equivalent to finding the largest multiset of orders that is feasible in at least two groups.

Given two groups we can calculate the largest such set by just taking the sum of the minimum of the number of elements over each of the $4$ possible orders $(1,2,4,8)$. Clearly if our multiset contains more elements of a given order than the first group then we can discard that group.

For $\mathbb Z_2^3$ and $\mathbb Z_8$ we get $1 + 1 + 0 + 0=2$

For $\mathbb Z_2^3$ and $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ we get $1+3+0+0 = 4$

For $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_8$ we get $1+1+2+0 = 4$.

We conclude that if we get $5$ orders then it is always possible to determine which group it is, but with $4$ or less it isn't possible, as for example, the orders $(1,2,2,2)$ could be feasible in $\mathbb Z_2^3$ or in $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: That helps, thank you for your answer. I did the same procedure with the order of the group being $16$ and I got an answer of $8$. The textbook answer says $12$.

Comment: when you do it for $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ versus $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4$ you get $1+3+8+0+0$. Also, I didn't realize it was for $16$ and not $8$ woops, but I guess it all worked out in the end haha @MichaelCatliMath

Comment: I also forgot to consider the isomorphism class $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$, so I think that’s why my answer differed. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure no problem, I added the case that yields $12$ in my previous comment. My pleasure .